# Call to a member function bindValue() on a non-object

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo, bindvalue

So I'm trying to create a prepared insert statement to a database for a web app. For the registration system, I'm feeding in values using post, then redirecting to a webpage to do the processing. However, I keep getting the error 'Call to a member function bindValue() on a non-object in /path/to/file.php on line 18, the first reference to bindValue(). The code is:

```
<?php

 session_start();

 require "database.php";
 $db = new Database("bills.db");

 $admin_password = $_POST['admin_password'];
 $admin_email = $_POST['admin'];
 $salt = sha1(time());
 $group_name = $_POST['group_name'];
 $group_password = $_POST['password'];

 $admin_hash = sha1($salt."--".$admin_password);
 $group_hash = sha1($salt."--".$group_password);

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO billgroup VALUES (NULL, :adminemail, :adminpassword_hash, :groupname, :password_hash, :salt)");
$stmt->bindValue(':adminemail', $admin_email, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$stmt->bindValue(':adminpassword_hash', $admin_hash, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$stmt->bindValue(':groupname', $group_name, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$stmt->bindValue(':password_hash', $group_hash, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$stmt->bindValue(':salt', $salt, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$results = $stmt->execute();




 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM billgroup WHERE adminemail = :adminemail");
 $stmt->bindValue(':adminemail', $admin_email, SQLITE3_TEXT);
 $users = $stmt->execute();
 $user = $users->fetchArray();
...
```

Comment: Is `$admin_email` set?

Comment: better use redbeanphp guys. it will handle everything

Comment: Yes, it takes in the value of the textbox on the previous page from post

Comment: But have you *checked* it?

Comment: Yes, just checked it, correct names and correct action on the form

Comment: Do your column counts match up? Six columns in your table? Not specifying column names is considered bad practice.

Comment: Another thing to note, is that when I comment out line 18, and put a NULL value in the INSERT statement, it then errors on line 19. I can only assume all of the bindValue() statements are broken?

Comment: You have ***three*** columns in the tables but you're trying to insert into ***six*** columns `(NULL, :adminemail, :adminpassword_hash, :groupname, :password_hash, :salt)`. That's causing the problem.

Comment: you want to conect to a sqlite database?

Comment: you solved your problem? , take a look to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want connect to a sqlite database but you have:

```
$db = new Database("bills.db");
```

You must know that you must have something like this:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:bills.db');
```

And change in all the bindValue calls the `SQLITE3_TEXT` to `PDO::PARAM_STR` like this:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':adminemail', $admin_email, SQLITE3_TEXT);
```

to:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':adminemail', $admin_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Maybe `Database` extends `PDO`... Or wraps around it. Or around an SQLite class. Who knows what's inside `Database`...!?

Comment: @Rudie Can be, but the problem is because $db is not a PDO object.

Comment: How do you know? If `Database extends PDO` it's a PDO object. You're probably right though.